# Common Bindings for Common Service Locator Library

Tags: binding, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container, structuremap

The [Common Service Locator Library](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) is a good idea, but it leaves me asking "Can we also make bindings somewhat generic?"

Certainly the differences between the concrete implementations (e.g. Structure Map, Unity, etc.) make it impossible to have a fully-common notion of bindings.  But it should be possible to fulfill the [80/20 rule](http://management.about.com/cs/generalmanagement/a/Pareto081202.htm).  Yes?

In other words, why not have a simple common set of bindings that cover most binding scenarios?  Perhaps the simplest common binding simply takes a tuple:

```
requested type, bound type, life-time-management-enum
```

Anyone make something like that before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Common Service Locator Library is a good idea

The CSL is solely meant as an abstraction for framework developers, since non-framework applications are much better off in applying the dependency injection pattern, which allows us to completely remove the need for a service locator.

> why not have a simple common set of bindings that cover most binding
>   scenarios?

It would be pretty 'easy' to define your own custom abstraction that can do this. The problem however is in this 80/20. Because of the differences each container has (and the devil is in the details) this abstraction will only work for the most trivial applications. For everything else, you will have to fallback interacting directly with the container which makes the abstraction useless.

But this all assumes that the problem with switching from container is in rewriting the basic "requested type, bound type, life-time-management-enum" statements, but this is a false assumption. Changing these lines can be done in a matter of minutes (since all your registration code is just in one place). The difficulty in switching from one container to another is however, the differences in support, for features like batch registration, registration of decorators, interception, lifetime scoping, register-resolve-release, etc, and the dependencies your application has on specific framework features.